# SQL Server Index Creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I need to create non clustered index on a table, I will be using 5 columns in the where clause. I will have to use include(Covering) to avoid lookup. Shall I create 5 non clustered index with include columns for each index or Shall I create one index with 5 columns with include columns. I will be having around 50 million records in it. What would be best for above given scenarios. Please suggest me the best way to increase the retrieval performance.

Comment: Can you show us the query or queries which you plan on running?  Whether or not you need to cover to avoid a lookup depends on what columns you plan to select.

Comment: Why you would need to create NC index, is that from query plan and do not need to create 5 indices i believe.

Comment: select subscription_name,duration,start_date,end_date,promotion_name,promotion_end_date,sub_total,discount,tax,line_item_total from billing.InvoiceItem lineItem inner join billing.Invoice invoice on lineItem.invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id where invoice.invoice_number='' and customer='' and ucid='' make='' and SERIAL_NUMBER='' and dcn='' and application=''

Comment: You should put this into your question, but from what I see any index would need a lookup because you are selecting columns besides the five columns you are considering in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using different column in select and where, so we need to have include columns. But I am not sure whether one index with colums(composite index) or separate index will be better. We need to update statistics and need to rebuild/reorganize index. Since I will be having more data. I will not be able to Rebuild 5 index within the given down time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What would be better composite index or 5 Index ?

Comment: Well for this particular query a composite index might perform better for the `WHERE` clause, but I would still expect a clustered index lookup for each record.  But the index you choose should be based on all queries you plan to run, not just one of them.

Comment: @timbiegeleisen I will be using that one query only.

Answer (score 0):

@Baskar,
I would suggest you to run this query and find the need to create Index, and you will understand in your table the need for 5 NC indices. This query is for Info only, do not need to create all Indices suggested by this query. Change you table name in where clause

```
SELECT TOP 10
dm_mid.database_id AS DatabaseID,
dm_migs.avg_user_impact*(dm_migs.user_seeks+dm_migs.user_scans) Avg_Estimated_Impact,
dm_migs.last_user_seek AS Last_User_Seek,
OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) AS [TableName],
'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) + '_'
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.equality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','') 
+ CASE
WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL
AND dm_mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN '_'
ELSE ''
END
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(dm_mid.inequality_columns,''),', ','_'),'[',''),']','')
+ ']'
+ ' ON ' + dm_mid.statement
+ ' (' + ISNULL (dm_mid.equality_columns,'')
+ CASE WHEN dm_mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND dm_mid.inequality_columns 
IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE
'' END
+ ISNULL (dm_mid.inequality_columns, '')
+ ')'
+ ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + dm_mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS Create_Statement
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups dm_mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats dm_migs
ON dm_migs.group_handle = dm_mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details dm_mid
ON dm_mig.index_handle = dm_mid.index_handle
WHERE dm_mid.database_ID = DB_ID() and OBJECT_NAME(dm_mid.OBJECT_ID,dm_mid.database_id) = 'MyTable'
ORDER BY Avg_Estimated_Impact DESC
GO
```

Comment: @B House, It does not give any result set.

Comment: @BaskarManoharan take off second where clause and run

Comment: @B House, Can you please explain the logic behind that query?

Comment: @BaskarManoharan This query suggests indices based on the average impact on execution plans and sub tree cost for the queries ran recently and self explainable as average_user_impact

Answer (score 0):

you run query with execution plan mode *(CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+L or CTRL+L)*. This mode suggest indexes. And create this.